# ElasticSearch query on tags

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I am trying to crack the elasticsearch query language, and so far I'm not doing very good.

I've got the following mapping for my documents.

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "jsondoc": {
            "properties": {
                "header" : {
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "properties" : {
                        "plainText" : { "type" : "string" },
                        "title" : { "type" : "string" },
                        "year" : { "type" : "string" },
                        "pages" : { "type" : "string" }
                    }
                },
                "sentences": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "id": { "type": "integer" },
                        "text": { "type": "string" },
                        "tokens": { "type": "nested" },
                        "rhetoricalClass": { "type": "string" },
                        "babelSynsetsOcc": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties" : {
                                "id" : { "type" : "integer" },
                                "text" : { "type" : "string" },
                                "synsetID" : { "type" : "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It mainly resembles a JSON file referring to a pdf document.

I have been trying to make queries with aggregations and so far is going great. I've gotten to the point of grouping by (aggregating) `rhetoricalClass`, get the total number of repetitions of `babelSynsetsOcc.synsetID`. Heck, even the same query even by grouping the whole result by `header.year`

But, right now, I am struggling with filtering the documents that contain a term and doing the same query.

So, how could I make a query such that grouping by `rhetoricalClass` and only taking into account those documents whose field `header.plainText` contains either `["Computational", "Compositional", "Semantics"]`. I mean `contain` instead of `equal`!.

If I were to make a rough translation to SQL it would be something similar to

```
SELECT count(sentences.babelSynsetsOcc.synsetID)
FROM jsondoc
WHERE header.plainText like '%Computational%' OR header.plainText like '%Compositional%' OR header.plainText like '%Sematics%'
GROUP BY sentences.rhetoricalClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE` clauses are just standard structured queries, so they translate to queries in Elasticsearch.

`GROUP BY` and `HAVING` loosely translate to aggregations in Elasticsearch's DSL. Functions like `count`, `min` `max`, and `sum` are a function of `GROUP BY` and it's therefore also an aggregation.

The fact that you're using `nested` objects may be necessary, but it adds an extra layer to each part that touches them. If those `nested` objects are *not* arrays, then do not use `nested`; use `object` in that case.

I would probably look at translating your query to:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "header",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "header.plainText" : "Computational"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "header.plainText" : "Compositional"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "header.plainText" : "Semantics"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, it could be rewritten as this, which is a little less obvious of its intent:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "header",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "header.plainText": "Computational Compositional Semantics"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The aggregation would then be:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "nested_sentences": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "sentences"
      },
      "group_by_rhetorical_class": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "sentences.rhetoricalClass",
          "size": 10
        },
        "aggs": {
          "nested_babel": {
            "path": "sentences.babelSynsetsOcc"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "count_synset_id": {
              "count": {
                "field": "sentences.babelSynsetsOcc.synsetID"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, if you combine them and throw away hits (since you're just looking for the aggregated result), then it looks like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "header",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "header.plainText": "Computational Compositional Semantics"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "nested_sentences": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "sentences"
      },
      "group_by_rhetorical_class": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "sentences.rhetoricalClass",
          "size": 10
        },
        "aggs": {
          "nested_babel": {
            "path": "sentences.babelSynsetsOcc"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "count_synset_id": {
              "count": {
                "field": "sentences.babelSynsetsOcc.synsetID"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are completely right, I should put more effort on reading the documentation but it's such a painful job to read their official doc. The only thing missing in my queries was the nested filter, I don't know how I could have missed that. Anyhow, thank you very much for your contribution